# why doesn't a simple python producer/consumer multi-threading program speed up by adding the number of workers?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, producer-consumer

The code below is almost identical to the python official Queue example at http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
from time import time
import sys

num_worker_threads = int(sys.argv[1])
source = xrange(10000)

def do_work(item):
    for i in xrange(100000):
        pass

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()

for item in source:
    q.put(item)

start = time()

for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    t = Thread(target=worker)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

q.join()

end = time()

print(end - start)
```

These are the results on a Xeon 12-core processor:

```
$ ./speed.py 1
12.0873839855

$ ./speed.py 2
15.9101941586

$ ./speed.py 4
27.5713479519
```

I expected that increasing the number of workers reduce the response time but instead, it is increasing. I did the experiment again and again but the result didn't change.

Am I missing something obvious? or the python queue/threading doesn't work well?

Comment: Even threads introduce a Little context-switching time. This is not as grave as for processes, but it exists.

Comment: if one CPU needs 12 seconds to do 10000 jobs four CPUs need 3 seconds to do the same jobs. Don't tell me that 27 - 3 = 24 seconds of it is because of context-switching.

Comment: Well, if YOU knew, you could tell. But if you don't, you'll need to consider that...

Comment: Threads were never intended to split jobs over several processors, although in some languages it it supported. However, in Python you would use processes for that.

Comment: @Mohammad: That is only true for very special cases. In most cases the job depends on things outside the CPU, such as the results of the previous calculations, and then you can't just add more processors and expect it to go faster anymore.

Comment: Finally, I switched to multiprocessing and everything seem to work fine. I think python threading is only advised when our application is more I/O bound than CPU bound. At least when we are using CPython.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python is rather poor at multi-threading. Due to a global lock only one thread normally makes progress at a time. See http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Answer (score 18):

Yeah, Maxim's right concerning the GIL.  But as soon as you do something worth doing in the worker, the situation changes in most cases.  Typical things to be done in the threads involve waiting for I/O or other things in which a thread-switch can be done quite fine.  If you don't just count numbers in your workers but instead simulate working with a sleep, the situation changes dramatically:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
from time import time, sleep
import sys

num_worker_threads = int(sys.argv[1])
source = xrange(1000)

def do_work(item):
    for i in xrange(10):
        sleep(0.001)

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()

for item in source:
    q.put(item)

start = time()

for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    t = Thread(target=worker)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

q.join()

end = time()
```

This gives the following results:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do echo -n "$i "; ./t.py $i; done
1 11.0209097862
2 5.50820493698
3 3.65133094788
4 2.73591113091
5 2.19623804092
6 1.83647704124
7 1.57275605202
8 1.38150596619
9 1.23809313774
10 1.1111137867
```

[image]