# How to synchronize two alternating threads

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I need to start two threads, controlling which one starts first, then having them alternating their jobs.

The following code works as expected with `do_sleep = True`, but it can fail with `do_sleep = False`.

How can I achieve the same result without using those ugly (and unreliable) sleeps?

The reason why it works with `do_sleep = True` is that:

- Each worker thread gives time to the other thread to start before trying to acquire the lock and start the next job
- There is a pause between the start of the first and the second worker that allows the first one to acquire the lock before the second is ready

With `do_sleep = False` it can fail because:

- At the end of each job, each thread can try to acquire the lock for the next cycle before the other thread, executing two consecutive jobs instead of alternating
- The second thread could acquire the lock before the first one

Here is the code:

```
import threading
import time
import random

do_sleep = True

def workerA(lock):
    for i in range(5):
        lock.acquire()
        print('Working A - %s' % i)
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 1))
        lock.release()
        if do_sleep: time.sleep(0.1)

def workerB(lock):
    for i in range(5):
        if do_sleep: time.sleep(0.1)
        lock.acquire()
        print('Working B - %s' % i)
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 1))
        lock.release()
        if do_sleep: time.sleep(0.1)

lock = threading.Lock()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=workerA, args=(lock, ))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=workerB, args=(lock, ))

t1.start()
if do_sleep: time.sleep(0.1)
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

print('done')
```

**EDIT**
Using a `Queue` as suggested by Mike doesn't help, because the first worker would finish the job without waiting for the second.

This is the wrong output of a version after replacing the `Lock` with a `Queue`:

```
Working A - 0
Working A - 1
Working B - 0
Working A - 2
Working B - 1
Working A - 3
Working B - 2
Working A - 4
Working B - 3
Working B - 4
done
```

This is the wrong output, obtained with `do_sleep = False`:

```
Working A - 0
Working A - 1
Working A - 2
Working A - 3
Working A - 4
Working B - 0
Working B - 1
Working B - 2
Working B - 3
Working B - 4
done
```

This is the correct output, obtained with `do_sleep = True`:

```
Working A - 0
Working B - 0
Working A - 1
Working B - 1
Working A - 2
Working B - 2
Working A - 3
Working B - 3
Working A - 4
Working B - 4
done
```

Comment: in reality this is really a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665367/why-doesnt-a-simple-python-producer-consumer-multi-threading-program-speed-up-b

Comment: No, I tried with the `Queue` and it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways to solve this. One relatively easy one is to use the lock to control access to a separate shared variable: call this other variable `owner`, it can either be set to A or B. Thread A can only start a job when `owner` is set to A, and thread B can only start a job when `owner` is set to B.  Then the pseudo-code is (assume thread A here):

```
while True:
    while True:
        # Loop until I'm the owner
        lock.acquire()
        if owner == A:
            break
        lock.release()

    # Now I'm the owner. And I still hold the lock. Start job.
    <Grab next job (or start job or finish job, whatever is required to remove it from contention)>
    owner = B
    lock.release()
    <Finish job if not already done. Go get next one>
```

The B thread does the same thing only reversing the `if owner` and `owner =` statements. And obviously you can parameterize it so that both actually just run the same code.

**EDIT**

Here is the working version, with the suggested logic inside an object:

```
import threading
import time

def workerA(lock):
    for i in range(5):
        lock.acquire_for('A')
        print('Start A - %s' % i)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('End A - %s' % i)
        lock.release_to('B')

def workerB(lock):
    for i in range(5):
        lock.acquire_for('B')
        print('Start B - %s' % i)
        time.sleep(2)
        print('End B - %s' % i)
        lock.release_to('A')

class LockWithOwner:

    lock = threading.RLock()
    owner = 'A'

    def acquire_for(self, owner):
        n = 0
        while True:
            self.lock.acquire()
            if self.owner == owner:
                break
            n += 1
            self.lock.release()
            time.sleep(0.001)
        print('Waited for {} to be the owner {} times'.format(owner, n))

    def release_to(self, new_owner):
        self.owner = new_owner
        self.lock.release()

lock = LockWithOwner()
lock.owner = 'A'

t1 = threading.Thread(target=workerA, args=(lock, ))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=workerB, args=(lock, ))

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

print('done')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the possibility of the wrong thread acquiring the lock, exclude relying on `time.sleep(...)` for correctness and shorten your code at the same time using [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) (two queues for both way communication):

```
import threading
import time
import random
from Queue import Queue

def work_hard(name, i):
  print('start %s - %s' % (name, i))
  time.sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 1))
  print('end %s - %s' % (name, i))

def worker(name, q_mine, q_his):
  for i in range(5):
    q_mine.get()
    work_hard(name, i)
    q_his.put(1)

qAB = Queue()
qBA = Queue()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=('A', qAB, qBA))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=('B', qBA, qAB))

t1.start()
qAB.put(1) # notice how you don't need time.sleep(...) even here
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

print('done')
```

It works as you specified. Alternatively you can use [`threading.Condition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#condition-objects) (a combination of `acquire`, `release`, `wait` and `notify`/`notifyAll`), but that will be more subtle, especially in terms of which thread goes first.

Comment: I notice that you don't use the `task_done()`. Is that common/correct?

Comment: `Queue.Queue` has a broad API and allows different usage scenarios. Above I'm using it as a channel between threads which is legal; another scenario is to fill the queue with objects to be processed and just call `join()` on the client thread, this call will block until `task_done()` is called for all objects by the processing thread(s). Worth noting that for IPC APIs for these scenarios were modeled after `Queue.Queue` but still separated: the first is supported by `multiprocessing.Pipe/Connection` and `multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue`; the second -- by `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue`.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried Gil Hamilton's answer and it doesn't work for me if I remove all the sleeps. I think it's because my 'main' thread keeps getting the priority. I found out that a better way to synchronize two or more threads is to use conditional object.

Here is my working alternate lock object with conditional object inside

```
class AltLock():
    def __init__(self, initial_thread):
        self.allow = initial_thread
        self.cond = threading.Condition()
        
    def acquire_for(self, thread):
        self.cond.acquire()
        while self.allow!=thread:
            print("\tLOCK:", thread, "waiting")
            self.cond.wait()
        print("\tLOCK:", thread, "acquired")
    
    def release_to(self, thread):
        print("\tLOCK: releasing to", thread)
        self.allow=thread
        self.cond.notifyAll()
        self.cond.release()
```

And this is an example usecase (the sleep statements in the thread are not required):

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = AltLock("main")
        
    def _start(self):
        print("thread: Started, wait 2 second")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("---")
        self.lock.acquire_for("thread")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("---")
        print("thread: start lock acquired")
        self.lock.release_to("main")
        return 0
    
    def start(self):
        self.lock.acquire_for("main")
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target = self._start, )
        self.thread.start()
        print("main: releasing lock")
        self.lock.release_to("thread")
        self.lock.acquire_for("main")
        print("main: lock acquired")

myclass = MyClass()
myclass.start()
myclass.lock.release_to("main") # house keeping
```

And this is stdout:

```
    LOCK: main acquired
thread: Started, wait 2 second
main: releasing lock
    LOCK: releasing to thread
    LOCK: main waiting         // 'main' thread try to reacquire the lock immediately but get blocked by wait.
---
    LOCK: thread acquired
---
thread: start lock acquired
    LOCK: releasing to main
    LOCK: main acquired
main: lock acquired
    LOCK: releasing to main
```