# Python - Thread And execution time

Tags: python, multithreading, time

I posted another question earlier, with a problem about two thread communicating. The main purpose of the code is to create a buffer and then put this into a file, while it keeps on buffering.

I made the first tests, and it worked perfectly. But it was quite long (from 40ms to 12s ... Randomly.).
I added some `print` to see what was happening.

```
def thread1()
    #Code Thread 1

def thread2()
    while(thread1.is_alive() == True)
        print '' (IMPORTANT LINE !!!)
        if #Condition over thread1
            #Rest of the code
```

And when I added that `print` (between `while` and `if`), my execution time consistently decreased (2 to 3 ms). The same results can be observed if i put a `time.sleep(0.000001)` instead of the `print`.

As a beginner, I think it's because the `while` loop is spammed with the condition, to go in the `if` loop, so that thread1 do not have time to do any operation. What do you think ?

Comment: Are you aware of Python's GIL (https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)?

Comment: Oh, that's why ! Thanks

Comment: This answer here might be interesting to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16666692/1281485